# How to automate creation of vocabulary questions

Tags: algorithm, vocabulary

We would like to prepare a quiz which will improve the vocabulary of the students.

What does pittance mean?

a) tiny, inadequate amount of payment
b) to feel pity or remorse
c) to go against, rebuttal an argument
d) regret, wishing you could take back what has been done or said

The answer to the above question is (a). So in order to create this question, the person creating the quiz provides a word and the right meaning and he has to look for 3 other choices. This is a time consuming process and we would like to automate this if possible. What logic should we use to create the other choices (it would be preferable to have the rest of the choices as close as possible to the original meaning, but aren't correct so that the time taken by the student to find the answer is tough).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That looks like a tough nut to crack. I would rather take the closest synonyms of "Pittance" and use their meanings as 2 of the choices.  You could do this by indexing a dictionary. AS to the fourth choice, generate a string with the substring word of the question. Like Pit for pittance. Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. So you are suggesting something like this..

Lookup synonyms for pittance (http://www.wordnik.com/words/pittance) and you will get allowance · alms · gift · quantity · little

Lookup meaning for allowance (http://www.wordnik.com/words/allowance) and maybe get the meaning as "An amount that is allowed or granted"

Lookup meaning for alms (http://www.wordnik.com/words/alms) and maybe get the meaning as "The act of relieving the needy; charitable aid; ministration to the poor: as, to give money in alms"

Comment: The last option cannot be pro-grammatically done as you cannot just dissect a smaller word from a bigger word randomly as you might end up with something which need not be a word.

Appreciate your inputs

Comment: Well they are some thoughts you can feed on...maybe mix them up or something. Did the synonyms generation be any help to your question automation?

Comment: I think it will as for as looking up synonyms are concerned, my worry is that the generated meanings are quite different than the meaning of the original word.